# Creating multidimensional arrays in iOS

Tags: ios, arrays, plist, multidimensional-array, records

So I'm new to iOS development and I really only rely on storyboards and youtube tutorials for iPhone app development. (Im using Xcode)

But for this project I need to create a list of names (around 200). When a name is tapped a record will appear (displaying the date of birth, height, nationality and possibly even a profile picture). I think it is called an array of records.

I was also wondering if I should be using `storyboards` or `xibs` for this particular project. I don't want to have to create 200 different view controllers for each person which is why I'm trying to implement an array.

Could someone give me a starting point with code and the basics to which I should proceed because I dont know where I should start.

Comment: Have you wired up a UITableView to a data source before?

Comment: No I've really only manually inputted data into the cells (graphically). I've never worked with code in UITable Views

Comment: This is not related to Xcode, you don't need Xcode for iOS development.

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention that

Comment: That's fine, H2CO3 has edited/retagged your question to not make it sound like an xcode problem.

Answer (score 5):

A general question - so a general answer.

Have a look at the Apple Tutorial - [Your Second iOS App](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/Introduction/Introduction.html).

This is a good starting point for writing data driven table view apps with Master and Detail views.

You'll probably want to use a different data model, but at least this should get you started.

Comment: Hey these are good tutorials, where can i find the third ios app tutorials and others

Comment: Does anyone know where i can find more tutorials like this?

Answer (score 2):

As a general approach, to create a two- or greater dimensional array of arrays, you can create an instance of an `NSArray` which holds references to other `NSArray` instances.

A simple one-dimensional array (what you really want for your example) is simply an `NSArray` of object references.

To answer more specifically, you would not need 200 view controllers, but one view controller to show a table view of `People` (an `NSArray` of `Person` instances) — let's call it `PeopleViewController` — and one view controller to show a table view with the attributes of one person (a `Person` instance) — let's call this a `PersonViewController`.

The `PeopleViewController` would likely be the "root" of your navigation stack, and it shows a table view with a list of all the people in your data set.

The `PersonViewController` gets pushed onto the navigation stack when you select an individual person from the list shown in the `PeopleViewController` table view.

If you have the index of the `Person` instance in the `People` array, then you need only pass the index and `People` reference to a `PersonViewController`. This view controller will then access the attributes of the `Person` instance at that index of `People`, and pour them into the detail table view.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to show a table of cells. The [UITableView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is generally used to accomplish this. There are number of [tutorials](http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/10/uitableview-tutorial/) on the Internet covering this topic.

When using a UITableView, you'll provide a configured view for each cell in the table. Based on the description of what you want to display, you'll probably need to make a [custom view](http://howtomakeiphoneapps.com/how-to-design-a-custom-uitableviewcell-from-scratch/1292/) with a view controller to use as the cells instead of using the default UITableViewCell.

In your code, you'll need to provide the data to the UITableView via its [delegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDelegate) and [data source](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDataSource). Take a look at [NSMutableArray](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html), it's probably what you'll want to use to store your array of objects for the row data. Also, your data for each cell should be stored in its own class so you can easily access its properties when you configure the cell views.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from Apple's "Your second iOS app" mentioned above, you may like the free iOS courses on iTunes U, I've only watched [this one from Stanford](https://itunes.apple.com/my/itunes-u/ipad-iphone-application-development/id473757255?mt=10), have a look at the lessons listing, its definitely worthwhile. It is last year's course however, *this* year, we no longer need to do @synthesize for properties. There are other ios courses on iTunesU that may touch on different aspects of ios dev. Then there are the [Apple Developer videos](https://developer.apple.com/videos/) too from WWDC.